# pexpect.spawn.interact returning an input/output error

Tags: python, pexpect

I use a python script to compile and run student fortran codes for me.  This works well as long as they follow the input convention that I give them.  Here is a sample of what works well for me:

```
child = pexpect.spawn(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file),name))
child.expect('')
child.sendline(input)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
self.r_output.append(child.before)
child.close()
```

When they do not follow my input convention, the expect command doesn't work.  For this reason I use the `child.interact()`.  But whenever the file finally terminates I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./project.py", line 263, in <module>
    main()
  File "./project.py", line 45, in main
    stud.tohtml(f)
  File "./project.py", line 173, in tohtml
    self.run("<br/>")
  File "./project.py", line 140, in run
    child.interact(chr(27))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1492, in interact
    self.__interact_copy(escape_character, input_filter, output_filter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1520, in __interact_copy
    data = self.__interact_read(self.child_fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1510, in __interact_read
    return os.read(fd, 1000)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

If I'm fast enough to press ascii 29 before it ends, everything goes great.  What could be wrong?  How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It probably means that the child exited. You could wrap the call in try/except and check  `child.isalive()` to make sure.